# Least square distances

Tags: matlab, line, points

I have two ordered arrays of x(`xcor`) and y(`ycor`) values. Joining the first and last points gives a line. I want to compute the perpendicular distances of all points from this line. This is similar to least square distance. Is there a direct way to do this in matlab?
Please also note that sign of the distance should represent the side on the points lie of the line.
[image]

```
 xy =
     -121.9067  -53.5483
     -122.0750  -53.5475
     -122.4750  -53.5243
     -123.0975  -53.4835
     -123.9050  -53.4168
     -124.8050  -53.3235
     -125.7025  -53.2467
     -126.5675  -53.1800
     -127.3825  -53.1215
     -128.1500  -53.0798
     -128.8825  -53.0468
     -129.6000  -53.0452
     -130.3150  -53.1133
     -131.0400  -53.2532
     -131.7850  -53.4513
     -132.5525  -53.6877
     -133.3425  -53.9345
     -134.1600  -54.1758
     -135.0075  -54.4115
     -135.8675  -54.6480
     -136.7375  -54.9040
     -137.5075  -55.2635
     -138.1875  -55.7435
     -138.7775  -56.3333
     -139.2850  -57.0665
     -139.8450  -57.9285
     -140.4550  -58.9492
     -141.1575  -60.0988
     -141.9825  -61.3415
     -142.9275  -62.6172
     -144.0050  -63.8517
     -145.2125  -65.0523
     -146.5450  -66.1715
     -147.9950  -67.1727
     -149.5575  -68.0570
     -151.2225  -68.8152
     -152.9925  -69.4493
     -154.8625  -69.9500
     -156.8300  -70.3063
     -158.8700  -70.5280
     -160.9050  -70.6017
     -162.8550  -70.6287
     -164.6525  -70.7372
     -165.5367  -70.7550
     -166.3450  -70.8620
```

Comment: This is a math problem. As I understand this problem, you have a set of points and a line. For each point, you want to find the shortest distance to the line. What you want to do is, for each point A, find a point on the line B such that segment AB is perpendicular to the line. Then everything else is trivial.

Comment: Note that you're calculating total least square distance here.

Comment: @MatthewGunn: many questions asked here are math problems. Often, Matlab has a built-in function to do that for you. Unfortunately not in this case.

Comment: @Jonas yeah you are right.

Comment: @Shai: How is this a duplicate of a Mathematica question? The geometrical problem is similar, but the language not quite.

Comment: What is a positive, what is a negative sign?

Comment: It doesn't matter but the same convention should be followed on all points.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have a vector AB, the distance from a point C to that vector can be calculated as follows:

- Normalize the vector AB
- Calculate the vector AC
- Project the vector AC onto AB
- Subtract the projection from AC
- Calculate the length of the result

In other words, you split AC into a component that is parallel to AB and a component that is perpendicular, and you calculate the length of the latter.

If you have arrays `x` and `y`, you can do the following

```
xy = [x(:),y(:)];
abVector = xy(end,:) - xy(1,:); %# a is the first, b the last point
abVectorNormed = abVector./norm(abVector);

acVector = bsxfun(@minus, xy, xy(1,:));

acParallelLength = sum(bsxfun(@times, acVector , abVectorNormed ),2);
acParallelVector = bsxfun(@times, acParallelLength, abVectorNormed );

perpendicularVector = acVector - acParallelVector;

perpendicularDistance = sqrt(sum(perpendicularVector.^2,2));
```

*EDIT* You asked for figures because the code "does not work" in your hands. See below the figures (top: raw data; bottom: perpendicular distance) and the command to plot them; the data looks fairly reasonable in my eyes.

[image]

```
subplot(2,1,1),plot(xy(:,1),xy(:,2),'or')
hold on, plot([xy(1,1),xy(1,1)+abVector(1)],[xy(1,2),xy(1,2)+abVector(2)],'b')
hold on, plot([xy(1,1)+acParallelVector(:,1),xy(:,1)]',[xy(1,2)+acParallelVector(:,2),xy(:,2)]','r')
axis equal %# important to see right angles as such
subplot(2,1,2),stem(xy(:,1),perpendicularDistance,'r')
ylabel('perpendicular distance')
```

Comment: It shows me this error: `Error using sqrt
Too many input arguments.` perpendicularVectoris 45x 2.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia: Sorry, typo. Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks for edit! What does AB represent here? Does it represent the line?

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia the line goes from point A to point B, thus I call it "abVector"

Comment: Can you plot the line computed and points. I am getting an incorrect answer, I just wanted to be sure. I have added points in the question for reproducing it.

Comment: I am unsure how you are representing the line with two parameters a and b instead of 3.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia: I've plotted the figures with all the lines. Result looks reasonable to me. Why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: Thanks so much! Sorry there some problem with my dataset. Can you please possible. Add sign to distance, that is, a point on right has +ve distance from the line and point on left has a negative distance from the line.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia: augment `perpendicularVector` and `acParallelVector` with a column of zeros, take the cross product (`cross`) and look at the sign of the third column of the result.

Comment: Please make changes in the answer.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia: Why? The question has not changed.

Comment: Okay I added it now. Please do so in the answer if possible.

Comment: Please update the answer that considers the sign soon.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia are you having difficulties implementing [Jonas's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33950784/least-square-distances#comment55829872_33951857), or are you just being needy?

Comment: I tried this.`sign_vector=cross([perpendicularVector,zeros(size(perpendicularVector,1),1)],[acParallelVector,zeros(size(acParallelVector,1),1)]);
signed_log=sign_vector(:,3)./abs(sign_vector(:,3));
perpendicularDistance=perpendicularDistance.*signed_log;
perpendicularDistance=perpendicularDistance(~isnan(perpendicularDistance));` It would be good to verify and accept the answer I guess.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia it very well should be. Note that you have to assign the bounty yourself to Jonas. Otherwise he won't get the bounty, since his answer is older than your bounty. (And even if the answer was newer, he'd only get *half* the assigned bounty automatically, which wouldn't be fair: he fully solved your problem, including additional constraints.). Also, note that you can just use `sign(sign_vector)` to avoid `NaN`s.

Answer (score 0):

```
function tot_distance=compute_distance2(x,y)
xA=x(1);xB=x(end);yA=y(1);yB=y(end);
a=(yA-yB); 
b=(xB-xA);
c=xA*yB-xB*yA;
d=0;
for p=2:numel(x)-1,
    d=d+(a*x(p)+b*y(p)+c)/sqrt(a^2+b^2);
end
tot_distance=abs(d);
end
```

Easier way.

Comment: This version doesn't give the same result as the sum of distances from @Jonas's answer. Are you sure it's correct? Shouldn't it give the same result?

Comment: @AndrasDeak What do you think is the mistake in this one?

Comment: It seems to use a different algorithm as the one of Jonas. I haven't tried to understand either of them, it just seems to me that they don't give the same result. This is why I asked if you get the same result, and if not, which one do you think is the correct one:)